# RSpec 3 undefined method `allow' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup...>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

```
describe '#messages' do
  subject do
    FactoryGirl.create :foo,
      :type => 'test',
      :country => 'US'
  end

  context 'when is not U.S.' do
    before{ allow(subject).to receive(:country).and_return('MX') }

    describe '#messages' do
      subject { super().messages }
      it { is_expected.to include 'This foo was not issued in the United States of America.' }
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to assign an attribute on the subject... I can't seem to get the incantation correct. Do I need a Double here? I'm not sure how that even works, and I apparently can't decipher the docs. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should define the `subject` variable as a helper method using [`let`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let). With this, you are defining a helper method that you can use everywhere in the file.

So, I'll modify your code as follows:

```
describe '#messages' do
  let(:subject) do
    FactoryGirl.create :foo,
      :type => 'test',
      :country => 'US'
  end

  context 'when is not U.S.' do
    before{ allow(subject).to receive(:country).and_return('MX') }

    describe '#messages' do
      subject { super().messages }
      it { is_expected.to include 'This foo was not issued in the United States of America.' }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is one of scope. you are calling the code in the `before` block before you've set up a `subject`

you'll need to either move the `subject` out into the outer context, move the `before` into the inner describe, or set up some alternative way of calling it so that `subject` is set up before running the `before`